# Do I Need to Replace This Tyre (Slight Cracking)

Tags: tires

I got my health check video through during my MOT which I passed. This tyre still has nearly 4mm tread left, but the garage advised replacing because of slight cracking, seen between the treads here. Looking for some extra advice, as I'm aware some garages will tell you anything for cash.

If it does need to be replaced, does it have to happen soon. A bit tight after Christmas.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The tire is coming to its end of life, suggest you replace as soon as possible.